# Eager Loading with hasManyThrough with Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

I have the following table structure;

```
users
user_id | email             | name
==================================
1       | tom@example.org   | Tom
2       | pete@example.org  | Pete

trainings
training_id | user_id   | title
=================================================
1           | 1         | First training of Tom
2           | 1         | Second training of Tom
3           | 2         | First training of Pete
4           | 2         | Second training of Pete

calendar
calendar_id | training_id   | when_date
=================================================
1           | 1             | 2014-08-01 10:00:00
2           | 1             | 2014-08-08 10:00:00
3           | 1             | 2014-08-15 10:00:00
4           | 2             | 2014-08-01 18:00:00
5           | 2             | 2014-08-03 18:00:00
6           | 2             | 2014-08-05 18:00:00
7           | 3             | 2014-08-12 16:30:00
8           | 4             | 2014-08-09 22:30:00
```

I have prepared three models for this table structure

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function trainings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Training');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Calendar', 'Training', 'user_id', 'training_id');
    }
}

class Training extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Calendar');
    }
}

class Calendar extends Eloquent {

    public function training()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Training');
    }

}
```

I want to get **latest N calendar events ordered by the nearest event first** for a selected user (`user_id = 1`) with all training details of this calendar event. When I do the following, the eager loading doesn't seem to work.

```
$events = User::with('events', 'trainings')->find($userId);

foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo $event->training->title; // runs a separate query to get the title of the training
}
```

If there are 100+ events for a given user, it runs 100+ queries.

How can I achive this with eager loading?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the code you posted. Wouldn't `$events` contain an instantiation of `User`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you fetch the user first and then query through that instance?

```
$user = User::find(userId);
$events = $user->with('events', 'trainings');
```

or in one go:

```
User::find(userId)->with('events', 'trainings');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by using lazy eager loading. In your case:

```
$user = User::with('events')->find($userId);
$user->events->load('training');

foreach ($user->events as $event) {
    echo $event->training->title;
}
```